# Can I ask a question on SO requesting somebdy to write code?

Tags: discussion, questions

As the title says, can I request somebody to write code for me. I need a algorithm which simulates the game of the cricket. I am not extremely knowledgeable in Mathematics and Probability so I wish someone could write a class or some functions for me. (c#)

Is it appropriate here, or on any StackExchange Website?

Comment: Nooooooooooooo!

Comment: [plz-give-me-the-codes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/plz-give-me-the-codes)

Comment: I hope this isn't serious.

Comment: If you need the algorithm, ask for the algorithm.

Comment: plz-pay-me-the-monies

Comment: You should probably go easier on the OP than you do people who just post on SO directly then voila, get the code.  +1.

Comment: I find this question shouldn't get downvoted. He's not asking for code, he's just asking if he can ask for code which I find legit.

Comment: @Oktav: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences

Comment: @Chichiray Thanks. I came here from stackoverflow and I should've read the FAQs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In general, no. Stack Overflow is a not a gimme-teh-codez site and if you openly ask someone to write that for you, the question will very likely get downvoted and closed within minutes.

However, we like to be deceived. The reality is that we get tons of write-the-codez-for-me requests each day and we do answer them, **if they are in a proper disguise**. So if you manage to put your problem into a proper, reasonably scoped question, explaining what you are trying to achieve, where you are stuck and maybe showing some approaches you tried, etc, chances are we will give you that code.

Comment: `Stack Overflow is a not a gimme-teh-codez site` - doesn't feel like that sometimes...

Comment: @tombull89 yeah, the old "in an ideal world" thing.

Comment: To clarify this answer, I assume there is no stackexchange site (not just stackoverflow.com) where you can ask people to write code for you, is that correct? Many new sites have emerged, but I don't think any of them allow this.

Answer (score 3):

It is not the purpose of StackOverflow. SO is based on its community to provide help, but help only. We don't code project from A to Z.

Comment: nor should you, my own experience is that I have been provided with some excellent skeleton code and excellent advice and insights.  Half the fun is exploring the code and what can it do.

Comment: There is excellent advices and code skeletons. But I never find a whole project on SO, this was the meaning of my answer.