# Profile Bug - Reputation Summary Not Displaying All Lines

Tags: bug, profile-page, daily-reputation-limit, reputation-summary

I noticed today that the reputation summary on [my Meta profile](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/216322/chue-x?tab=summary) is displaying only one line:

[image: rep-summary-me-meta]

---

Normally, it should display four lines, such as in my Stack Overflow profile:

[image: rep-summary-me-so]

---

The bug is reproducible in other profiles of users that also participated in the [meta discussion of the now infamous "croissant" question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190106/dealing-with-find-out-whos-going-to-buy-the-croissants). Here is a screen shot for one of those participants:

[image: rep-summary-booth]

---

I do have a lead on the cause, but I don't have it pinpointed. It seems to be happening to those users who have hit the rep cap (200 points), and also have other activity that, because of the cap, does not count.

For example, I have 5 events under "yesterday" that do not have any associated points:

[image: rep-detail-me-meta]

Comment: Maybe when you reach rep cap it stops looking further?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - I'm not sure on that to be honest. It does work correctly in another place: when I hover the mouse pointer over my name on the top status bar, the summary popup shows the correct events.

Comment: Good point, both appear to have the same source. Let's hope the devs will find and hunt down this bug. :)

Comment: Problem still exist and observe it today on my profile, It also hide the view more link http://i.stack.imgur.com/wYSMh.jpg