# A way to encourage/enforce constructive comments rather than anonymous down-votes. Please discuss

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I believe this is different from other similar questions such as [General Attitude: Stack Overflow: Non-constructive attitude, rather than constructive criticism [duplicate]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191029/general-attitude-stack-overflow-non-constructive-attitude-rather-than-constru)

My question is not about encouraging politeness, it is about providing a simple automated way to increase positive, constructive feedback.

My suggestion is that a down-vote could be required to have an associated comment so that the down-voter is identified.

You might object that this would encourage revenge voting. Not so IMO. The revenge voter would also have to provide sensible reasons for their down-votes. It would be obvious if someone was doing it vindictively.

Please discuss both the benefits and drawbacks of this idea.

Thank you.

Comment: Too many duplicates... tough to choose just one... check out http://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=downvote+require+comment+is%3Aquestion

Comment: Only if upvoters also have to provide comments with their votes.

Comment: @fbueckert there is a feature request for that: [Force members to leave comments when they upvote](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289607/839601)

Answer (score 4):

> My suggestion is that a down-vote could be required to have an associated comment so that the down-voter is identified. You might object that this would encourage revenge voting.

That could indeed lead to revenge voting, but that isn't the most important thing: voting is anonymous, whether it is an up-vote or a down-vote doesn't matter. I often do wonder why people up-vote, but there isn't a dialog for that too (while the effect is worse than the other way around).

> The revenge voter would also have to provide sensible reasons for their down-votes.

That would indicate some reviewing mechanism. Also, voting is subjective, so we can't really argue there can be a consensus on a good or bad vote (unless we are talking about the outer 10% of course where it is quite obvious how one should vote)