# What are the typical reasons for a network wide suspension?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension, network-wide-suspension

I have come across a user profile that has been recently suspended until January *network-wide*. I have checked out all his various SE accounts and could not find a single negatively voted post in his five newest posts on any SE account. In fact, on some he was obviously quite productive.

So with a user like this I would wonder why he was suspended network wide. What are typical reasons for network-wide suspensions and why might a productive users like this one suddenly be suspended?

Comment: Maybe the reasons are to be found in his _deleted_ posts. :)

Comment: Unless you are a mod, you won't see his deleted posts listed in his profile.

Comment: You can link to it, but we can't disclose any of the relevant details.

Comment: [This is the user in question](http://stackexchange.com/users/2092607/brian-rushton?tab=accounts) His Math and MathOverflow accounts are pretty good. He was certainly a productive user on those.

Comment: Typical suspensions exist on one site for a day or so, but the more naughty the person gets the longer each suspension is likely to get. By that logic this person was *very* naughty. We may be curious what happened, but that's no reason to actually be told why. Just assume they were very naughty.

Comment: Yes. Very naughty.  Bad user... no biscuit.

Comment: If the answer is the actual reason, might it not be polite to remove the comments above which cast doubt on his character? Could be a bluff, it the "he's naughty be we can't tell you" people *did* check first.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Wrong. You're a mod. You should know this. It's moderators _and_ people with 10k or more rep. As for the user, does that mean no waffles or [croissants](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190106)?

Comment: If you're underaged, and SE finds out, you will be suspended network-wide until you turn 13.

Comment: @ColeJohnson: You can see deleted posts.  But you *can't* see a list of deleted posts in their profile.

Comment: @RobertHarvey whoops. Misread your comment. My mistake

Comment: [This answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323366/why-not-avoid-the-streisand-effect-for-network-wide-suspensions/323450#323450) to [Why not avoid the Streisand Effect for network-wide suspensions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323366/why-not-avoid-the-streisand-effect-for-network-wide-suspensions) addresses this question directly, and the answers here are inadequate.

Answer (score 13):

The user's [Mathematics profile](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/51970/brian-rushton) says:

> Please suspend my account for 6 months for a breather!

This seems to be an unusual but effective way to battle SE addiction.

Comment: Wow, that's weird! Okay that seems very plausible. Still though, my question is what are the typical reasons for network-wide suspension.

Comment: Yeah, that would do it alright.  First time I've ever seen this actually used, however.  I guess the next logical thing is 12Steps.SE.  Area51, anyone?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not sure a 12steps.SE for SE addicts is such a good idea. Kind of like holding AA meetings in a bar. Made be laugh though.

Comment: _Six_ months? Sounds kind of...excessive? I get being addicted to unicorns, waffles, Skeet, and more, but one month should be _more_ than plenty of time.

Comment: Yeah I've done this before, but not for such a long time, and not Network wide. It happened just after I discovered chat 

Answer (score 5):

There are no "typical reasons".

Each suspension has its own story.

We can't, and should not, dig into those things.

Comment: Sometimes there are "political" things behind the cages, not all of them happen for some problematic behavior or voting irregularity, openness could make the things only more clear. If the community could see, who were caged and why, it would make the things imho better.

Comment: @peterh maybe, and maybe not. Guess we will never know.

Answer (score -5):

Disclaimer: I have mainly rumors, so it is not sure info.

1. Campaigning for a network-wide suspension during an active suspension on some of the SE sites. My source didn't specify what is counted as "campaign".
2. Coming back during a suspension with a different account.
3. Technical attack against the SE Network.

In the case of any more reasonable information, I am ready to edit this post or delete it.

Comment: The question asked for "typical reasons" not possible reasons. I may be wrong but I doubt suspensions for technical attacks against the network are all that common.

Comment: @Cai Unfortunately, in the lack of authentic information, we must live what we have. My answer estimates the typical reasons and not the possible reasons. I can't consider your "critic" constructive, even not a little bit.