# Letter and Envelope Pairing Audit Question

Tags: discussion, review-audits

This does not seem like a good question for auditing purposes: [Algorithm : Letters and envelopes pairing](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/3950344)

It does not appear to be about programming, it appears to be "what's your favorite greedy algorithm", and would probably be a better fit for a math/puzzles site.

Forgive me if I am missing something really obvious.

Answer (score 3):

Just because a question *might* be on-topic elsewhere doesn't mean it's off-topic here.

In this case, the author has already identified an algorithm that works, but he's looking for something more efficient. Not "favorite", mind you - *faster*.

The relevant discussions here would probably be:

- [Are questions about algorithms on topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97869/are-questions-about-algorithms-on-topic)
- [How can I prevent closure on language-agnostic algorithms questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194523/how-can-i-prevent-closure-on-language-agnostic-algorithms-questions)

For what it's worth, 9 people have been audited with this question; only 3 failed that audit, including yourself.

Comment: hmm... isn't 33% failure rate kinda... high? (I still agree the question should stay open)

Comment: Here's a similar question that's up for closure. Its also asking for a "fastest algorithm". I voted to leave it open based on the feedback given here. It might make another good audit question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21565721/what-is-the-fastest-php-message-processing-solution-for-a-large-number-of-messag.

Comment: That one's not a particularly good audit because it's not a particularly good question otherwise, @noloader. He doesn't describe the specifics of what he's doing very well, or where he's looking to improve performance.