# Lost 40 reputation points, bug?

Tags: support, reputation, deleted-questions, users

I noticed that I lost 40 reputation points on Stack Overflow today. I checked my reputation history and this is the reason it gave me:

> -10   19 mins ago     removed     User was removed
>
> -30   19 mins ago     removed     Where is Visual Studio Express?

I did answer a question about where Visual Studio was located about a week or so ago, but I can't find it now.

I'm guessing that the original person who asked the question deleted his account and so all his questions got deleted as well, but why remove the reputation on the answer?

Comment: 10k+ link to the question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731274/where-is-visual-studio-express

Comment: This should be common sense, it explains "User was removed" which means that any up-votes that user gave something of yours have also been deleted, therefore voiding the rep you gained from it.

Answer (score 11):

The user itself voted on your answer, and the `+10` you received for that post is now gone with the user.

In addition, with [the question (and your answer to it)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731274/where-is-visual-studio-express) now gone, you lost the +30 you received for the other votes on your answer.

The question was auto-deleted when the user was deleted, because it had a negative score (-6).

You always lose the reputation previously gained from deleted posts; with an exception for posts over 6 months old and a score of 3 or more. Your post had a score of 4 but was not old enough.

Comment: You might want to mention that rep is lost only if the question is deleted within the first 60 days of it being posted. I believe that is the period. You may need to verify.

Comment: @JoshMein: That's correct, but less pertinent here.

Comment: If you notice the last sentence, he is asking why the reputation was removed. It seems like it is pertinent. He seems to know that the question was deleted.

Comment: @MartijnPieters While that question wasn't a big deal, I would have been mad if it was a question that I spent a lot of time working on the answer. Thanks for your quick response.

Comment: @Caesar: That's always the risk when answering questions that really are off-topic or of terrible quality.

Comment: @MartijnPieters While the question could have been terrible, the answer was good and a few up voted it so why punish the answerer a well?

Comment: @Caesar: You could try to convince a moderator to undelete the post, but I wouldn't hold your breath.

Comment: @Caesar: As for why this happens: because there are plenty of ways of abusing the system and by defaulting to deletion-deletes-votes-too you get to remove a big incentive to posting crap content just for the votes on the funny meme picture you happened to include.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I have never seen an answer on SO that had a joke or a meme that had any votes on it. This site is very strict and people are very harsh, even when the answer is partially correct. Besides, if someone does do that then they should be down voted.

Comment: @Caesar: See [Dealing with "Find out who's going to buy the croissants"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190106) for an example that went to +53 before finally deleted.

Comment: @Caesar - That means that these sorts of rules are working. :)